# ArgumentError 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

An error occurs while trying to create a database

Text of the error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\AlNews\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 108, in _init_items
        spwd = item._set_parent_with_dispatch
    AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:/Users/Alex/Desktop/AlNews/news_app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
        from model import db
      File "c:\Users\Alex\Desktop\AlNews\news_app\model.py", line 5, in <module>
        class News(db.Model):
      File "c:\Users\Alex\Desktop\AlNews\news_app\model.py", line 7, in News
        title = db.Column(db.text, nullable=False)
      File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\AlNews\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1388, in __init__
        self._init_items(*args)
      File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\AlNews\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 113, in _init_items
        "'Constraint' expected, got %r" % item
      File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\AlNews\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
        reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
      File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\AlNews\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 152, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\AlNews\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 108, in _init_items
        spwd = item._set_parent_with_dispatch
    sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected, got <function text at 0x0000000003869288>
```

models.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class News(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.text, nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    published = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    text = db.Column(db.text, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<News {} {}>'.format(self.title, self.url)
```

Comment: `db.text` is a function.  Where you looking for `db.Text` or `db.String(max_length)` as the datatype for those columns?  Have a look at https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/

Comment: @SimonCrane , Thank you very much) indeed, for several hours I could not understand what the problem was)) It turned out I just did not notice)

Answer (score 1):

As [Simon Crane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12094894/simon-crane) observes in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59522705/argumenterror-schemaitem-object-such-as-a-column-or-a-constraint-expected#comment105216529_59522705), the problem here is a simple typo: a column has been defined using the *function* `db.text` like this:

```py
class News(db.Model):
    ...
    title = db.Column(db.text, nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    ...
```

but it should have been defined using the *column type* `db.Text`:

```py
class News(db.Model):
    ...
    title = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    url = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    ...
```

The error message

> ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected, got <function text at 0x0000000003869288>

is telling you that SQLAlchemy expects a column type in the class definition, not the function object that has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs in the cases where the data type of columns specified has some conflicts in it. In your case, the conflict is with `db.text` which you passed it as a type for columns of class `News`. Kindly check if the name of data types and the name of classes in db files are the same at any point in time. They shouldn't be.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the `db.text` to `db.String()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).